# Ubuntu 16.04 LXD Openstack Network

Tags: networking, 16.04, openstack, lxd

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on 4 Nodes, Installed Openstack Mitaka, one node as compute, running nova-lxd.
After installation, I can login to the dashboard, create a new instance, using LXD as the hypervisor / container, and startup the instance, no problems. Neutron is running on the compute node as well.

Once the instance is started, it gets a private IP on the dashboard, as configured by Openstack, but "lxc list" shows no ip address. Logging into the instance directly with lxc exec, show an interface, eth0, with no ip.

My question is how to configure the network component of Openstack to provide the allocated address to the LXD instance once it has started. Do I need the lxdbr0 ? Do I need any specific change to the neutron configuration files / ml2 ini files ?

Appreciate your help,

D,

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure `lxdbr0` by

`dpkg-reconfigure -p medium lxd`

Maybe it's because `lxdbr0` is not configured yet.
Let me know if it works for you.